# Calendar Workflow not working

Tags: workflow, calendar, pause, send-email

I am trying to read a calendar and whenever it finds a task it sends a mail.

[image]

Comment: Any error occured or other symptoms you seen?

Comment: Thx for teh reply!
 No not really it works fine the first time it does sends a mail but the next day I receive nothing!

Comment: For testing you have received the right emails. So do you have checked it by changing the date? Check it once, so that you can find the issue or bug. Without any error message/reason we can't do anything!

Comment: For starter I found that error: 01/03/2017 10:15:00.67 OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0990) 0x15CC SharePoint Server General 7201 Critical ActiveDirectory Import failed for ConnectionForectName 'npone.com', ConnectionSynchronizationOU 'DC=NPONE,DC=COM', ConnectionUserName 'NPONE\m.ayach'. Error message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007052E): The user name or password is incorrect.